# How in cypress to refer to an input that does not have an id

Tags: html, css, input, cypress

I have a field in which you need to write a name for the application. If I try to find this field in Cypress via class I get an error:

```
cy.type() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contains 40 elements.
```

How should I refer to this element if it does not have an "id, type", etc.?

```
<div class="app-name-option"><label>App Name</label><input class="form-control" value=""></div>
```

[image]

Comment: You could:

You could add an `id`, or any other identifier if you have access to the frontend code. Also, I think you can select it like so: `cy.get('label').contains('App Name').siblings()` I haven't test it

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Unfortunately, I do not have access to the frontend code. I will try your option, thanks

Comment: Let me know if it works, I am curious

Comment: @ManuelAbascal yes it worked, I was surprised it was so easy)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can combine the [contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains) & [siblings()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/siblings) methods like so:

```js
cy.get('label').contains('App Name').siblings().type('my app name');
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.siblings()` command can return multiple elements, so it's better to use it with a selector

```js
cy.contains('label', 'App Name')
  .siblings('input')
  .type('my app name')
```

Answer (score 2):

In the browser when you inspect your target element, if you right-click, you'll see a copy option that will have the option to copy the CSS selector for that specific element, you can use it for selecting the specific element.
[image]

But be aware, if this element doesn't have a unique identifier (like Id, or data-* attribute), the selector will be a brittle selector, which may can satisfy the current situation, but the maintenance of the tests is kind of tricky. (small changes in the project, will cause break the selector and break the tests).

read more about selector best practices in the [cypress document](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements)

Answer (score 2):

The input is part of an element group marked by `<div class="app-name-option">`.

Sometimes it's easier to work with the group outer element, identify it by class and text of it's inner label.

```js
cy.contains('.app-name-option', 'App Name')
  .find('input')
  .type('AppName')
```

In this case, the class is unique so it's sufficient to identify the outer element.

```js
cy.get('.app-name-option')
  .find('input')
  .type('AppName')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rest of the your HTML within the form node in your DOM, here are a few ways you may want to do this.

```js
// get form and limit input search in form
cy.contains('form', /App Name/i)
  .find('input')

// in case there are multiple inputs within form
cy.contains('form', /App Name/i)
  .contains('div', /App Name/i)
  .find('input')
```

Comment: Yes, copy paste. I updated it.

Comment: Also `cy.contains('form div', /App Name/i)` is a bit shorter.